# Unique constraint violation on non-unique index

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Sometimes I get a unique key violation error for an index that isn't unique.

I have an Oracle 10g database.

There are two indexes on different tables for which is happens. Their details are:

```
CREATED                    14-JAN-14 20.14.11
LAST_DDL_TIME              14-JAN-14 20.14.11
OWNER                      MEDDBA
INDEX_NAME                 STATUS_REQUEST
INDEX_TYPE                 NORMAL
TABLE_OWNER                MEDDBA
TABLE_NAME                 STATUS
TABLE_TYPE                 TABLE
UNIQUENESS                 NONUNIQUE
COMPRESSION                DISABLED
PREFIX_LENGTH    
TABLESPACE_NAME            MEDTBS
INI_TRANS                  2
MAX_TRANS                  255
INITIAL_EXTENT             65536
NEXT_EXTENT                1048576
MIN_EXTENTS                1
MAX_EXTENTS                2147483645
PCT_INCREASE    
PCT_THRESHOLD    
INCLUDE_COLUMN    
FREELISTS    
FREELIST_GROUPS    
PCT_FREE                   10
LOGGING                    YES
BLEVEL                     1
LEAF_BLOCKS                89
DISTINCT_KEYS              67
AVG_LEAF_BLOCKS_PER_KEY    1
AVG_DATA_BLOCKS_PER_KEY    2
CLUSTERING_FACTOR          190
STATUS                     VALID
NUM_ROWS                   8161
SAMPLE_SIZE                8161
LAST_ANALYZED              01-APR-14 22.00.09
DEGREE                     1
INSTANCES                  1
PARTITIONED                NO
TEMPORARY                  N
GENERATED                  N
SECONDARY                  N
BUFFER_POOL                DEFAULT
USER_STATS                 NO
DURATION                   
PCT_DIRECT_ACCESS          
ITYP_OWNER                 
ITYP_NAME                  
PARAMETERS                 
GLOBAL_STATS              YES
DOMIDX_STATUS    
DOMIDX_OPSTATUS    
FUNCIDX_STATUS    
JOIN_INDEX                NO
IOT_REDUNDANT_PKEY_ELIM   NO
DROPPED                   NO
```

```
CREATED                     14-JAN-14 20.14.04
LAST_DDL_TIME               14-JAN-14 20.14.04
OWNER                       MEDDBA
INDEX_NAME                  SEQUENCE_ID2
INDEX_TYPE                  NORMAL
TABLE_OWNER                 MEDDBA
TABLE_NAME                  SEQUENCE
TABLE_TYPE                  TABLE
UNIQUENESS                  NONUNIQUE
COMPRESSION                 DISABLED
PREFIX_LENGTH   
TABLESPACE_NAME             MEDTBS
INI_TRANS                   2
MAX_TRANS                   255
INITIAL_EXTENT              65536
NEXT_EXTENT                 1048576
MIN_EXTENTS                 1
MAX_EXTENTS                 2147483645
PCT_INCREASE    
PCT_THRESHOLD   
INCLUDE_COLUMN  
FREELISTS   
FREELIST_GROUPS 
PCT_FREE                    10
LOGGING                     YES
BLEVEL                      1
LEAF_BLOCKS                 43
DISTINCT_KEYS               1
AVG_LEAF_BLOCKS_PER_KEY     43
AVG_DATA_BLOCKS_PER_KEY     120
CLUSTERING_FACTOR           120
STATUS                      VALID
NUM_ROWS                    7795
SAMPLE_SIZE                 7795
LAST_ANALYZED               01-APR-14 22.00.10
DEGREE                      1
INSTANCES                   1
PARTITIONED                 NO
TEMPORARY                   N
GENERATED                   N
SECONDARY                   N
BUFFER_POOL                 DEFAULT
USER_STATS                  NO
DURATION    
PCT_DIRECT_ACCESS   
ITYP_OWNER  
ITYP_NAME   
PARAMETERS  
GLOBAL_STATS               YES
DOMIDX_STATUS   
DOMIDX_OPSTATUS 
FUNCIDX_STATUS  
JOIN_INDEX                     NO
IOT_REDUNDANT_PKEY_ELIM    NO
DROPPED                    NO
```

The error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; ORA-00001: unique constraint (MEDDBA.STATUS_REQUEST) violated; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (MEDDBA.STATUS_REQUEST) violated
```

Comment: Are you doing some `DELETE` operation on the underlying table? I've just got same error on a table. Index reported in error message is not unique. There is no unique constraint on column of that index. But it has probably something to do with delete operation on that table, as we are doing (in scheduled procedure): `delete from tests where time_flag < limit;` `commit;` `execute immediate 'alter table tests modify lob (test_data) (shrink space)';` `execute immediate 'alter table tests shrink space';` `commit;`. Error disappeared when I did `drop index ...` and then recreated it again.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a surprise if you have unique constraint on the table based on non-uniuqe index - Oracle allows this to support deferrable constraints:

```
SQL> create table t (x int, y int);

SQL> create index t_x on t(x);

SQL> alter table t add constraint t_x unique (x)
  2  /

SQL> select uniqueness from user_indexes where index_name = 'T_X';

UNIQUENES                                                                       
---------                                                                       
NONUNIQUE                                                                       

SQL> insert into t values(1,2);

SQL> insert into t values(1,2);
insert into t values(1,2)
*
error in line:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.T_X) violated
```

So you should check your table which probably has correspondent constraints.

Comment: In your example, you're using different names for the index and the unique constraint. This doesn't match the scenario of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you there's a unique *CONSTRAINT*. You can have a constraint and index with the same name, e.g.

```
create table t1(pk number);
create index t1_idx on t1(pk);
alter table t1 add constraint t1_idx unique(pk);

insert into t1 values(1);
insert into t1 values(1);
```

raises the exact same error you're getting.

So, if this column isn't supposed to be unique, you can drop the constraint with

```
alter table <table_name> drop constraint <constraint_name>;
```

And, BTW: If you really have a table named `SEQUENCE`, I strongly recommend renaming it. `SEQUENCE` is a reserved word, and having a table with this name will cause you a lot of pain in the future.

Comment: I can't find a constraint with the same name: `select count(*) from all_constraints where constraint_name in ('STATUS_REQUEST', 'SEQUENCE_ID2');` yields `0`. If I try to drop them, it says 'Cannot drop constraint - nonexistent constraint'.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but did you run this statement as the MEDDBA user? `all_constraints` doesn't necessarily show you all constraints in the database.

Comment: I ran it as MEDDBA user with all_constraints and user_constraints, and as SYSTEM with all_constraints and dba_constraints. Are there any others to try?

Comment: No, dba_constraints shows really all constraints. That's strange - can you drop the index and check whether the problem persists?

Comment: That's the plan, but as it's only being observed on a live system, there's obviously processes and approvals to go through which take time.

Comment: Did you check all the constraints in `dba_constraints` on that table (not just by constraint name)?

Comment: From everything I've been able to find, a unique index violation will still give a ORA-0001 error and say 'constraint'.